# CakePHP pagination

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I've got some wierd problem with Pagination, the code:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'Visit' => array(
        'limit' => 10
    )
);
$visits = $this->Paginator->paginate('Visit');
echo count($visits);
```

And count give me: page 1 = 0, page 2 = 6, page 3 = 10, page 4 = 7, ...
Why? I thought that paginator id doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM visits LIMIT 10 OFFSET pageNumber
```

I've got 4 realtions with visits table, maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Works fine for me, I get the same number on `count($visits)` for every page, and the sql is `SELECT * FROM visits LIMIT {$offset}, {$limit}`. Is this just an "I was wondering" question? Or is this giving you errors (like having different number of visits per page or something like that)? If this gives you an actual error, can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: It's giving me errors... i've got different count for visists on every page

edit: I mean different = it's not 10 visists, eg. for 16 pages i've one page with ten visits

Comment: try $visits = $this->paginate(); rather than $visits = $this->Paginator->paginate('Visit');

Comment: set debug to 2 and show the executed sql.

Comment: executed sql return 10 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Someone was deleting from return some elements by afterFind function in AppModel class. I checked VisitModell class but didnt check upclass, damn... so stupid. So sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions'=>array(
    'all conditions'...,
    ),
    'limit' => 10,
    'recursive'=> 0 or -1
));
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
$visits = $this->Paginator->paginate('Visit');
echo count($visits);
```

Comment: unfortunately, still i've got the same result

Comment: do you want to assign your conditions on pagination only?